# Is there a way to use a relative address that doesn't go over the edges of the file?

Tags: cursor-movement

I'm using the following commands to move a line of text up and down in the file.

```
:move +1<CR>
:move -2<CR>
```

However, these commands don't work on the edges of the file. If I try to move the first line up or the last line down I get an error that says `E14: Invalid Address`. Is there a way to avoid this error? I'd prefer if attempting to move past the edges of the file became a no-op instead.

I'm wondering if there is another way to specify the target address instead of +1 and -2, which would tell Vim that I don't want to go outside the bounds of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
:silent! move +1<CR>
:silent! move -2<CR>
```

`:silent` suppresses normal messages, while `:silent!` also suppresses error messages.

See `:h :silent`.

**Disadvantage**: This suppresses all kinds of error messages.

If you want a mapping for this, you could check the line before executing:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <C-Up> :if line('.')!=1 \| exe "move -2" \| endif<cr>
:nnoremap <silent> <C-Down> :if line('.')!=line('$') \| exe "move +1" \| endif<cr>
```

Here `<silent>` just prevents echoing the command. See `:h :map-silent`.

---

Update because of comment:

In visual mode try the following:

```
:vnoremap <expr> <C-Up> line("'<")!=1 ? ":'<,'>move '<-2<cr>" : ''
:vnoremap <expr> <C-Down> line("'>")!=line('$') ? ":'<,'>move '>+1<cr>" : ''
```

A map-expression (`:h :map-expression`) returns the keys to execute. Here it is combined with a conditional.

For UP check if the first selected line is not line 1. If yes -> move, else do nothing.

For DOWN check if the last selected line is the last line of the file. If yes -> move, else do nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I do want to put those commands in a mapping, in which case those if statements are exactly what I want. Is there a way to make them also work for a visual mode mapping? If I start the visualmode mapping with `:if` if errors with "E481: No range allowed".

Comment: That's because the range is in front of the `if`. Also it is not that easy. If you mark 3 lines a `:move +1` will result in an error (E134: Cannot move a range of lines into itself). In that case you would need `:move +3`. If you also want to cover that, I guess you need a function that handles those cases. Will answer later.

Comment: I am currently using `:move \`>+1` and `:move \`>-2` as my mapping for visual mode. They do the right thing if a range of lines is selected but they also break near the edges of the file.